# ffmpeg mp4 files don't play to end

Tags: ffmpeg

I have created an mp4 from images and audio files using this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i tmp/part1/frame0.png -i tmp/part1/audio0.mp3 -i tmp/part1/frame1.png -i tmp/part1/audio1.mp3 -i tmp/part1/pause0.5.mp3 -shortest -filter_complex "[1:0][4:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a1];[3:0][4:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a3];[0:0][a1][2:0][a3]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec libx264 -qp 0 tmp/part1/out.mp4
```

This produces a video with 2 frames and an audio track. Somehow however, when playing this video in VLC, The last frame isn't shown, and when uploaded to youtube, the video length is shown incorrectly.

How can I avoid this bug? Is there a simple workaround to it?

Answer (score 1):

Loop the images for some limited time (less than the audio segments).

```
ffmpeg -y
  -loop 1 -t 2 -i tmp/part1/frame0.png
  -i tmp/part1/audio0.mp3
  -loop 1 -t 2  -i tmp/part1/frame1.png
  -i tmp/part1/audio1.mp3
  -i tmp/part1/pause0.5.mp3
  -shortest
  -filter_complex "[1:0][4:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a1];
                   [3:0][4:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a3];
                   [0:0][a1][2:0][a3]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"
  -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec libx264 -qp 0 tmp/part1/out.mp4
```